# C# unable to assign cookiecontainer to asmx web service client

Tags: c#, web-services, cookies, soap

I'm attempting to connect to a asmx web service in C# using visual studio 2012 express.

The documentation says to assign a cookiecontainer to the web service like follows:

```
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;    /// using appropriate references
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

//   Create an instance of the Web Service and assign in
//   a cookiecontainer to preserve the validated session

ServiceRef.WSClient wsClient = new ServiceRef.WSClient();

CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
wsClient.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
```

But, that results in error:

```
'WebServiceTest.ServiceRef.WSClient' does not contain a definition 
for 'CookieContainer' and no extension method 'CookieContainer' 
accepting a first argument of type 'WebServiceTest.ServiceRef.WSClient' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly 
reference?)
```

I've tried adding "allowCookies" to app.config.  That doesn't seem to work; calling ws methods that require being logged in (having a cookie set) fail.  Fail means I get a message about a problem with the xml they return (they're returning some non-xml error presumably).

I'm totally new to C#, SOAP based web services, and visual studio, but I've seen numerous code examples that use code exactly like mine.  For example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol.cookiecontainer.aspx

http://megakemp.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/

Comment: How did you add the service reference? Does the WSClient object have your WebService methods?

Comment: From main menu, "Project", "Add Service Reference", and then enter the url pointing to the .asmx page.  And yes, I can call a login method and a ping method provided by webservice.  All other methods provided by the service require being logged in.

Comment: allowCookies should automatically set the cookies with cookies that you are receiving in previous responses. Is that what you want or are you setting them manually with predefined values? I forgot to mention it in my answer.

Comment: Also, is the asmx service under your control?

Comment: No, I'm just a consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using a `WCF service reference` client that doesn't contain a `CookieContainer` property.

[The post that you referenced](http://megakemp.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/) actually contains methods for dealing with cookies on `WCF service reference` clients, The simplest being the `allowCookies` config property, which would automatically pass cookies that were received in previous responses.

If you would like to use the older types of clients (`Web Reference`, which have the `CookieContainer` property) you can follow [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx).

Comment: I had tried "allowCookies" but since there was another binding already in my app.config it did not work.  I removed the "name" and "config" binding options and it seems to work now.